# Can I access 32 bit postgres database with 64 bit postgres application?

Tags: database, postgresql

Without doing a dump and restore can I use an existing 32 bit postgres database using a 64 bit postgres executable?

Comment: What do you mean by "executable" : the frontend, or the DBMS-server?

Comment: I meant the DBMS server

Comment: In theory, the DBMS-server should *not* depend on the underlying `sizeof (objects)` It is is all present in the catalogs. In *practice* it does depend on the physical sizes. Plus: there is the calling convention for .so and all that. In short: **yes: you should dump&restore**

Comment: I have actually done this.  In fact, the 32-bit server was Windows, and the 64-bit one was Redhat.  It worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The client and server communicate via tcp/ip.

If you use the libpq binary protocol you have to be aware of type sizes, but otherwise it makes no difference.

You must make sure the client has the correct architecture libpq / psqlODBC / whatever client driver you are using. It must be the architecture of the client app, not the server.